# In a command out put read particular line and executed in another command

Tags: bash, shell

I need a script for read nth line output from a command and excuted it another command.

Here is the example

i need output from the zpool status and i collect the disk information from the zpool status

```
# zpool status
   pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool   ONLINE       0     0     0
          c7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

and executed in format

```
format c7d0
```

how do we write the shell script for this. i am new to shell script and tried different ways but it's not worked. Can anyone please suggest appropriate shell script for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So given `zpool status` you want to show the line of `c7d0`? Can you show your attempts to make the picture more clear?

Comment: You want to read the nth line; what is the value of n?

Comment: Well, this would work for your immediate example: `zpool status | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 format`. But if you need something more general than that, you'll probably need to explain a little better.

Answer (score 0):

nth line is `|sed -n ${n}p`

e.g. 15th line of the output of `seq 20`:

```
> seq 20|sed -n 15p
15
>
```

you'll need to give more details for me to help any further

Comment: my requirement is from zpool status command i have to select disk which is 7 th filed and print it in format command

Comment: I still don't fully understand your question, but something like this might work: `zpool status|sed -n 7p|awk '{print $1}'|xargs format`. Does that do what you need?